# About Chern insulator

Tags: topology, topological-insulators, topological-order, topological-phase

I know when we talk about Insulator, U(1)charge symmetry naturally exists.
But in this article:[Quantum phase transitions of topological insulators without gap closing](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-8984/28/40/405502), the author claims that:
"The Chern insulator is not an SPT phase protected by U(1)charge symmetry. In fact, a Chern
insulator (and the QHE) is **neither topologically ordered** (or **long-ranged entangled**) nor symmetry-protected. It is simply a chiral phase due to broken time-reversal symmetry".
In this question:[Do Chern Insulators (QAHE) have topological order (long-range quantum entanglement)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/463466/do-chern-insulators-qahe-have-topological-order-long-range-quantum-entangleme/466195#466195)
, Professor Wen says that:
Chern Insulator has "invertible" **topological order and long-range entanglement**. Chern Insulator does not need any symmetry, although one usually **assume** Chern Insulator has an U(1) symmetry.
So how to understand two explanations?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your confusion comes from conflicting definitions of LRE. Wen's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/265981/193472) should hopefully clear things up.